# CSS 3 Level Navigation snap to parent

Tags: css, html, navigation

I have looked at a few tutorials and other questions here that are close, but was unable to get my head around some of the code. I tried ask follow up question in the comment sections, but I am unable to because I just joined StackOverflow and don't have a high reputation to do it.

I am working on a 3 level navigation using css for practice and ran into a little snag.
The issue I am having is getting the 3rd level to "snap" into place with the 2nd level drop down. If you have a moment below is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/JustALittleHeat/4KnP2/3/#&togetherjs=akTj3NGGcf

You will see it is a horizontal navigation bar HOME CATEGORIES WORK ABOUT etc...
When you hover over the WORK menu it drops down vertically and then when you hover over the menu items on that tier they display another sub menu to the right. However the sub menu to the right does not move down to match its corresponding parent.  What am I missing in my code to "snap" it down?  Are declaring classes limiting my ability to get the results I want as opposed to path of element selectors?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>`enter code here`
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets/styles2.css"

</head>

<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li class ="menuHeader"><a class="menuHeaderText" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class ="menuHeader"><a class="menuHeaderText" href="#">Categories</a>
<ul class="dropDown">
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Development</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Web Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class ="menuHeader"><a class="menuHeaderText" href="#">Work</a>
<ul class="dropDown">
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Company A</a>
<ul class="dropDown2">
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Branding</a></li>
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Advertising</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Company B</a>
<ul class="dropDown2">
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Marketing</a></li>  
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
</ul>                     
</li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Company C</a>
<ul class="dropDown2">
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Advertising</a></li>
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
</ul>                        
</li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Company D</a>
<ul class="dropDown2">
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Branding</a></li>
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Marketing</a></li>
<li class="lvl2SubMenu"><a class="lvl2subMenuText" href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>                 
</li>
<li class ="menuHeader"><a class="menuHeaderText" href="#">About</a>
<ul class="dropDown">
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Company</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a class="subMenuText" href="#">Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class ="menuHeader"><a  class="menuHeaderText"href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#menu, #menu ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; z-index:0;}

#menu {width: 960px; height: 40px; margin:60px auto; border: 1px solid  #222;background-color:#111; 
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#555, #444 5%, #333 15%, #999 25%, #111 75%);
       background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#555, #444 5%, #333 15%, #999 25%, #111 75%);
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#555, #444 5%, #333 15%, #999 25%, #111 75%);
       background-image: linear-gradient(#555, #444 5% ,#333 15%, #999 25%, #111 75%);
       border-radius:6px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333, 1px 1px 2px #FFF inset; Transition:all 1s ease-in-out; }


.menuHeader {float:left; border-left:thin solid rgba(153,204,255,0.3); position:relative; 
            -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
            Transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

.menuHeader:hover  {background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#555, #777 5%, #555 15%, #FFF 25%, #111 75%);
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #FFF inset }

.menuHeaderText {float:left; padding:12px 30px; text-decoration:none; color:white; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font:bold; font-size:14px;}



.dropDown { width:120%; opacity:0; visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top: 38px; z-index:1;
           background:#444; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #333; Transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;}

.subMenuText {width:90%; float:left; padding:5%; text-decoration:none; color:white; 
             font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-bottom:thin solid rgba(153,204,255,0.3);
             Transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;}      

.dropDown a:hover {background:rgba(0%,80%,100%,1); width:90%; }

  #menu li:hover > ul {opacity:1; visibility:visible; margin:0;}


.dropDown2 { width:120px; opacity:0; visibility:hidden; position:absolute; display:inline-block; left:100%; z-index:1;
           background:#444; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #333; Transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;}



.lvl2subMenuText {width:90%; float:left; padding:5%; text-decoration:none; color:white; 
             font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-bottom:thin solid rgba(153,204,255,0.3);
             Transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;}

#menu li ul li:hover  > ul li {opacity:1; visibility:visible; margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4KnP2/4/
this should do what you wanted

`float:left` changed to `display:inline-block` on `.subMenuText`